# Inline Form won't stay inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img width="40" height="40" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1904/3.0">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item  <% if (pageName === " home") { %> active <% } %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item  <% if (pageName === " profile") { %> active <% } %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item  <% if (pageName === " postnow") { %> active <% } %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/postnow">Post Now</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="navbar-nav">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="button" onclick="window.location='/logout'">Log
                    Out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is my code, which yields the following result:
[image]

Apparently the Inline Form is not inline, which troubles me. I don't know how to configure it.

I doubt the error is in the Bootstraps file, but I'm not sure it is.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1:**
I moved the form out of `\ul`, didn't work.

**UPDATE 2:**
I added a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` in front of it, didn't work either.

Comment: Please update your answer to have a code snippet that yields the result you picture above.

Comment: `<form>` elements are **not** allowed to be child elements of `<ul>` elements. [Use a validator](https://validator.nu/). Write valid HTML. Then worry about the way it looks.

Comment: @Quentin I changed but it didn't work sir

Answer (score 0):

```
you are using bootstrap 5. Please check this for better solution:
```

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/#inline-forms